# SQL SUM values where 2 conditions are met

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select

I am trying to create a query that calculates credit and debit for each month. the values are in column called SUM and there is a field for each record that says if it is credit or debit (ex_type). I have manage to get the total sum of all the fields (although it is not correct as well - cos I am just sum all the values no matter if it is credit or debit).

```
SELECT sum(sum) as total FROM acc where month='$month'
```

But I cannot figure out for to do it for Credit and Debit

So, to summarize... I want to have the following two queries combined in one.

```
1. Select sum(sum) as Debit from acc where ex_type='Debit' and month='$month'
2. Select sum(sum) as Credit from acc where ex_type='Credit' and month='$month'
```

So, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is this mysql or sql-server?  Do you want one value back (total) or three (Debit, Credit, Total)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this with `CASE`

```
Select sum(CASE WHEN ex_type='Debit' THEN `sum` ELSE 0 END) as Debit,
sum(CASE WHEN ex_type='Credit' THEN `sum` ELSE 0 END) as Credit FROM ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Select sum(d.sum) as Debit, 
  (Select sum(c.sum) from acc c where c.ex_type='Credit' and c.month='$month') as Credit
from acc d where d.ex_type='Debit' and d.month='$month'
```

However if you supply more details on other fields one could inner join onto the same table and that may be slightly more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe duplicate post :

[SUM() based on a different condition to the SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655219/sum-based-on-a-different-condition-to-the-select)

Try this :

```
Select 
   SUM(CASE WHEN ex_type='Debit' THEN `sum` ELSE 0 END) as Debit,
   SUM(CASE WHEN ex_type='Credit' THEN `sum` ELSE 0 END) as Credit
FROM acc 
Where etc...
```

Comment: I saw that post, but it is a bit different I think

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a MySQL expert, but you might want to try the following

```
SELECT 
  SUM(CASE WHEN ex_type='Debit' THEN sum ELSE 0 END CASE) as SumOfDebit,
  SUM(CASE WHEN ex_type='Credit' THEN sum ELSE 0 END CASE) as SumOfCredit,
FROM acc
WHERE
  month = '$month'
```

MySQL [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) 5.0 deals with the CASE statement if this doesn't work as expected

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    SUM(sum) as total
    SUM(IF(ex_type='Debit',sum,0)) Debit
    SUM(IF(ex_type='Credit',sum,0)) Credit
FROM acc 
WHERE month='$month'
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest (and coolest) way is:

```
SELECT 
  SUM((ex_type='Debit') * sum) Debit,
  SUM((ex_type='Credit') * sum) Credit,
FROM acc
WHERE month = '$month'
```

This works because in mysql, true is 1 and false is 0.