# SQL/MS Access 2013 conditional sum using searched CASE expression

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2013

In my Access database I have three tables, 'mission', 'missionAssets', and 'equipment'.  Each mission has a start time and an end time, and can have many assets.  Each asset entry has correlating missionID from the mission table, an assetName that correlates to an entry in the equipment table, and a quantity being used on that particular mission.

[image: schema]

Mission:

```
missionID (PK)  start                   end                     destination   description
1               10/17/2015 6:00:00 AM   10/17/2015 5:00:00 PM       
2               10/18/2015 6:00:00 AM   10/18/2015 5:00:00 PM       
3               10/19/2015 6:00:00 AM   10/19/2015 5:00:00 PM
```

MissionAsset:

```
assetID (PK)    missionID (FK)   asset (FK)   quantity    description
1               1                M1088        2           
2               1                10K          3    
3               2                M1088        1
4               3                M1120        1
```

Equipment:

```
AssetName (PK)        OnHand       Inoperable
M1088                 10           2
10K                   8            1
M1120                 4            0
```

My table joins are correct for the query.  I want to make a few sums that are filtered by time periods: in example, what quantity of each asset will be used 24 hours from now?  I've tried using:

```
Sum(CASE WHEN mission.start <= (Now()+1) AND (Now()+1) <= mission.end THEN quantity ELSE 0 END)
```

to no avail; Access trips a 'syntax error (missing operator)'. I referenced [SQL sum with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517681/sql-sum-with-condition) to find documentation on the searched CASE expression (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).  I also referenced [Is it possible to specify condition in Count()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400078/is-it-possible-to-specify-condition-in-count) where a simple CASE expression is used.

Comment: Please provide schema and sample data.

Comment: try `iif(cond_1, true_value_1, iif(cond_2, true_value_2, else_value))`