# How to select aggregate of values within a date range from a table

Tags: mysql, sql

Let me just give a simplified example to illustrate what I mean.

Let's say we have a table named **accounts** with columns **deposits**, **dmonth**, and **dyear**.
Select **sum(deposits)** will get the sum of **ALL** values under the deposits column.
What is the SQL query to get sum of deposits for, say, period **earlier** than **July 2016**

Comment: `SELECT SUM(deposits) as Deposits_Sum WHERE CONVERT(int, dyear+dmonth) < 201607` - Depending on how year and month are stored, you'll have to change the `201607` part. My example assumes year is stored as 4-digit and month as 2-digit.

Comment: Months less than october are stored as single digits e.g as 7 not 07, so will 20167 be correct?

Comment: Yes that should work!

Comment: Comparing Dec 2015 and Sept 2016, is 201512 < 20169 ? This one is a bit tricky.

Comment: We could tell you for sure if you provide some sample data. There is a lot of guessing going on below

Comment: Duh @bodesam, not sure how I did not think of that. You could convert single digit months to double digit, however truthfully I much prefer Aaron D's answer to my own. I'd suggest going that route instead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way:

```
SELECT SUM(Deposits)
FROM   Accounts
WHERE  (dYear = 2016 AND dMonth < 7)
OR     dYear < 2016
```

Comment: Thanks. Nice, but it wont capture years earlier than 2016

Comment: Sorry. OR     dYear < 2016  should take care of that.

Comment: @bodesam Yup, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your `dyear` and `dmonth` or stored, you may need to do something like this:

`SELECT SUM(deposits) as Deposits_Sum WHERE CONVERT(int, dyear+dmonth) < 201607`

What i've done here is combined your `dyear` and `dmonth` to create a value that's chronologically sortable. I then convert this to an integer for comparison purposes.

Using this logic, we can find all records where this value is less than July 2016 by doing `< 201607` in the `WHERE` clause. This final piece may require some modification if your years are not stored as `yyyy` and/or your months are not `MM`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming dmonth contains something date time like you could do this with a where clase

```
Select sum(deposits) as Sum from accounts where dmonth < 07-01-16 00:00:000.000
```

See also:

[SQL sum with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517681/sql-sum-with-condition)

Comment: I'm assuming `dmonth` does not contain the full date only because he has a separate `dyear` column. Again, just an assumption.

Comment: Good point Tyler, we definitely need to know the value of dmonth and a little more clarity in terms of how far back they are trying to go, just this year, forever, etc.

Comment: Not just this year. Period is arbitrary.