# mysql query error: SQL sum with condition

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my code:

```
select assignedstfid, staffname, staffsymbol, SUM(case where bookingstarttime > '2021-03-31' then TIMESTAMPDIFF (minute, bookingstarttime, bookingendtime) else 0 end) as lengthofworking from crm.bookingtable, crm.staffinfo where staffinfo.staffid = bookingtable.assignedstfid GROUP BY assignedstfid ;
```

and there is a syntax error about 'select' saying that 'select is not valid in this position for this server version, expecting " ( " with' ...

How could I fix this?

the query is based on this question([SQL sum with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517681/sql-sum-with-condition))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One obvious error in your query is `case where` instead of `case when`.

In addition:

- The `GROUP BY` columns should be consistent with the unaggregated `SELECT` expressions.
- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.
- Use table aliases and qualify column references.

So, this might work:

```
select bt.assignedstfid, s.staffname, s.staffsymbol, 
       sum(case when bookingstarttime > '2021-03-31'
                then timestampdiff(minute, bt.bookingstarttime, bt.bookingendtime) else 0
           end) as lengthofworking
from crm.bookingtable bt join
     crm.staffinfo s 
     on s.staffid = bt.assignedstfid 
group by bt.assignedstfid, s.staffname, s.staffsymbol ;
```